# How to write a function to return a javafx stage

Tags: javafx, canvas

I need to write a function which returns a Stage. But the class must extend Application in order to work which prevents it returning an object

```
public class addRectanglesToCanvas extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public Stage start(Stage stage){ 
        // Create the Canvas
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 200);
        // Set the width of the Canvas
        canvas.setWidth(400);
        // Set the height of the Canvas
        canvas.setHeight(200);

        // Get the graphics context of the canvas
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // Draw a Text
        gc.strokeText("Hello Canvas", 150, 100);

        // Create the Pane
        Pane root = new Pane();
        // Set the Style-properties of the Pane
        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        // Add the Canvas to the Pane
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        // Create the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        // Add the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the Title of the Stage
        stage.setTitle("Creation of a Canvas");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();

        return stage;
    }
}
```

the code will not compile and gives the following error "The return type is incompatible with Application.start(Stage)"

Can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: The solution depends on what the method you're trying to implement is supposed to do. Currently this looks like you're trying to add a return type to the `start` method for no apparent reason. (You're not even invoking the method anywhere...)

Answer (score 4):

By calling the method `start(Stage stage)` you are overriding  [Application#start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-) which has a different signature.

To have a method that receives a stage and modifies it and returns it, just use a different name:

```
 public Stage configureStage(Stage stage){/* your code */};
```